Popper.js Adds Unintended 24px Offset with position: fixed
I'm encountering an issue when using Popper.js in conjunction with a fixed-positioned element.
Situation:

I have a <div> element with position: fixed and top: 24px:
<div id="fixed-element" style="position: fixed; top: 24px;">
  <!-- Content -->
</div>


Below this element, I place another <div> that I want to position using Popper.js with strategy: 'fixed':
const reference = document.querySelector('#fixed-element');
const popper = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(popper);

Popper.createPopper(reference, popper, {
  strategy: 'fixed',
  modifiers: [
    {
      name: 'offset',
      options: {
        offset: [0, 10],
      },
    },
  ],
});



Problem:
When I apply Popper.js, it automatically adds the existing 24px from the top property to the specified offset. This results in the popper element being positioned 24px lower than intended. I want Popper to account for the existing 24px and only apply the specified offset.
Question:
Is there a way to configure Popper.js to consider the 24px top position, or can I retrieve this value and adjust the offset manually? Alternatively, is there a better approach to handle this positioning with fixed elements?

If you need to position an element that is relative to your parent element,  then you need to specify not 'fixed' but 'absolute' then the element will be located relative to the parent element.

If your content will simply be located in the middle of the block with a fixed position, then it is enough to add indents through "padding'
